# Update springboot 2.7.8 to 3.2.1 - restTemplate not working in spring 3x

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, resttemplate

`org.apache.httpcomponents.client5:httpclient5:5.2.1`.

I have updated httpcomponent maven dependency to httpclient5.

when i tried to hit my restTemplate api it is throwing error as mentioned below.

```java
public ResponseEntity<String> sendPostRequest(RestTemplate restTemplate, String url, Object requestBody, HttpHeaders headers) {`
    HttpEntity<Object> request = new HttpEntity<>(requestBody, header);
    return restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);
}
```

```
[nio-8801-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/digital-provider] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.hc.core5.http.ClassicHttpResponse org.apache.hc.client5.http.classic.HttpClient.executeOpen(org.apache.hc.core5.http.HttpHost, org.apache.hc.core5.http.ClassicHttpRequest, org.apache.hc.core5.http.protocol.HttpContext)'].
```

I tried updating the httpcomponent version and etc but nothing works.

Thanks in advance can anyone let mw know what is the mistake im making im not sure i have updated the things but the existing code itself breaking.

Comment: Can you show your full pom.xml as well as the complete stack trace? See [mcve].

Comment: Have you manually defined versions of dependencies (like `httpcomponent maven dependency to httpclient5.`)? If so do not do that.... use the ones provied by SB... also better would be to upgrade first to 3.0. Also check the release notes and after that upgrade to higher versions... very important read the migration guides...

Comment: Yes thank you so much for the answers and suggestions after upgrading the httpclient5 to version 5.2.1 things are working fine.